# CKEditor 4 Dropdown Button to Insert Placeholder

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I found two separated plugins: `StrInsert` and `Placeholder`. The first plugin create dropdown menu that insert string and the second plugin insert placeholder.

here's the screenshot for `StrInsert` plugin:
[image: strinsert]

and for `Placeholder`plugin:
[image]

There has been so many questions on the Internet asking for similar function **(To make a dropdown that insert a placeholder)**, yet there's no solution/ plugin that provides this functionality. Here's the link for the plugins: [StrInsert](http://ckeditor.com/addon/strinsert) and [Placeholder](http://ckeditor.com/addon/placeholder)

I have asked this question on `ckeditor` forum too. But, just in case somebody else here has done this before, I need your help.

**============================EDIT =========================================**

Here's what `StrInsert` does, 
[image] when one of the dropdown menu is clicked, it will insert a `text` into the editor. However, instead of inserting a `text`, I want it to insert a `placeholder`.

`Placeholder` can be inserted using another plugin called `PlaceHolder`, how is it differ from `text`? It has yellow background color and most importantly, the user can't erase the letter [image]

Comment: solution for what? you haven't defined what your problem is

Comment: To make a dropdown that insert a placeholder instead of text. I put the question on the title, I will edit my post as well

Comment: doubt you will get much help if you don't provide more detail than `insert a placeholder`. As it currently stands have absolutely no idea what your expectations are

Comment: @charlietfl I have added more information, please let me know if it's still not clear.

Comment: @charlietfl http://zolson.wordpress.com/2011/04/19/ckeditor-placeholder-select/ this is close to what I want, but the dropdown isn't as good as using `StrInsert` plugin. I hope it helps

Comment: @Limantara How is the one you linked not as good as StrInsert? What do you want the plugin to be like? Does it have to be a placeholder and not just any old widget? This sounds like a really easy plugin but I can't bring myself to do it if I don't know what to aim for :)

Comment: @Nenotlep From the tutorial on my comment above, I could create the dropdown here's the screenshot: https://imgur.com/J6K44KF, However as you can see, it has a pop up window before the dropdown. What I want is similar to what `StrInsert` does, it doesn't have pop up window when clicked. I'm glad you find it easy, many people need this plugin :)

Comment: @Edwin With what kind of solution did you end up? Mind to share?

Comment: @CodeClown I modified the plugin. Here you can have it https://github.com/Limantara/DropdownPlaceholder

Answer (score 4):

Yes this can be done, and can be done with what you already have.

In summary - the Placeholder plugin does a nice job of representing the placeholders as self contained yellow elements, and the StrInsert plugin offers a convenient method of inserting pre-defined strings from a drop-down list rather than having the user type them into a dialog.

Therefore, a simple solution to get the best of both is to use both - StrInsert to insert placeholder strings. It works as you describe and uses the standard functionality of each plugin.

Steps as follows:

1. Start with both plugins installed as standard. I don't think I need to describe that bit here.
2. The StrInsert plugin allows you to define its string values within its plugin script file. Instead of putting regular strings in there, add your strings in placeholder format.

   e.g. Change the default strings below...

   // array of strings to choose from that'll be inserted into the editor
   var strings = [];
   strings.push(['@@FAQ::displayList()@@', 'FAQs', 'FAQs']);
   strings.push(['@@Glossary::displayList()@@', 'Glossary', 'Glossary']);
   strings.push(['@@CareerCourse::displayList()@@', 'Career Courses', 'Career Courses']);
   strings.push(['@@CareerProfile::displayList()@@', 'Career Profiles', 'Career Profiles']);

   to make them your desired placeholders...

   // array of strings to choose from that'll be inserted into the editor
   var strings = [];
   strings.push(['[[Something]]', 'Something', 'Something']);
   ...
3. Finally, if you don't need the Placeholder button as well then you can remove it (just the button) by using the entry in the normal config.js in the ckeditor folder. There may already be a removeButtons line in there that you can add CreatePlaceholder to, but in any case it'll look something like this:

   config.removeButtons = 'CreatePlaceholder';

Comment: Also double clicking on the existing place holder [[Something]] will bring up the dialog box to create a new place holder.  In addition to above I also commented out "dialog: 'placeholder'," within the placeholder/plugin.js

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a bit old, but I created a plugin to do exactly this task.

I've created the "Placeholder Tokens From Dropdown" plugin for CKEditor.  It works in much the same way as the strinsert plugin that Simon is talking about, although with more flexibility.

You can pass in a config including a 'format' (in case you don't want to use the pleceholder plugins format).  It uses the placeholder format by default [[something]], but can use anything else (For example {{something}}).

The placeholder tokens can be passed in as a JavaScript array via the config.  The plugin will do the rest for you.

I hope that this helps

https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/placeholder_select

Comment: Hi did you provide a way to localize the "Insert placeholder" label & text?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Token Insertion](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/token) plugin. It creates select dropdown with preconfigured values. You can config value, it's name in dropdown list and inserted value prefix/postfix symbols