# ckeditor plugin strinsert: how to set custom strings after initialization

Tags: ckeditor

I'm trying to implement fixed placeholders to ckeditor by using plugins [placeholder](http://ckeditor.com/addon/placeholder) and [strinsert](http://ckeditor.com/addon/strinsert) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393581/ckeditor-4-dropdown-button-to-insert-placeholder).

Unfortunately I'm not able to alter `strings` array of plugin `strinsert` dynamically.

This lines in `config.js` should work but it does not:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.strinsert_strings = [
        ['[[foo]]']
    ];
};
```

Maybe this plugin does not support altering strings array after init?

How could I do to present users different placeholders in different ckeditor instances without cloning strinsert plugin x times?

NB: I'm using newest versions of all of them.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: I do not need this plugin any longer. It works w/ placeholder only too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set custom placeholders dynamically by using `dialogDefinition` event.
I did it like this (html attribute `data-placeholders` specifies the valid placeholders in form of `"placeholder1,different text to show=placeholder2,another text=placeholder3"`

```
  CKEDITOR.on ('dialogDefinition', function (e) {

    // Check if the definition is from the dialog window you are interested in (the "Link" dialog window).
    if (e.data.name == 'placeholder') {
      var $textarea = $(e.editor.element.$),
        placeholders = $textarea.attr("data-placeholders"),
        tab, ff, i, a;

      //placeholders = [['placeholder1'],['Text to show', 'placholdervalue']];
      if (placeholders && placeholders.length) {
        // convert placeholders from desc1=val1,desc2=val2,val3,... format to array(array(desc,val))
        placeholders = placeholders.split(",");
        // ensure placeholders is array of arrays with exact 2 members
        for (i = 0; i < placeholders.length; i++) {
          a = placeholders[i].split("=");
          if (a.length < 1) a[1] = a[0];
          placeholders[i] = a;
        }
        tab = e.data.definition.getContents ('info');

        // Set the default value for the URL field.
        ff = tab.get ('name');
        ff['type'] = 'select';
        ff['items'] = placeholders;
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Like suggested use the placeholder rplugin instead. Just edit the file `ckedit/plugins/placeholder/dialogs/placeholder.js`. Change the the element type to `select` and add the required value to `items` like in the following example:

```
contents: [
            {
                id: 'info',
                label: generalLabel,
                title: generalLabel,
                elements: [
                    // Dialog window UI elements.
                    {
                        id: 'name',
                        type: 'select',
                        style: 'width: 100%;',
                        label: lang.name,
                        items:[
                            ['ONE'],
                            ['TWO'],
                            ['THREE']
                        ],
                        // SNIP...
```

Answer (score 0):

For strinsert, I got it to work by editing its plugin.js, get rid of the strings declaration and replace with:

```
var strings = editor.config.strinsert_strings;
```

Then in your html before creating CKEDITOR:

```
CKEDITOR.config.strinsert_strings =  [];
CKEDITOR.config.strinsert_strings.push(['myvalue1', 'myname1', 'mylabel1']);
CKEDITOR.config.strinsert_strings.push(['myvalue2', 'myname2', 'mylabel2']);
CKEDITOR.replace('mytextarea');
```